# setting selected to nil with select tag in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Hi I am trying to set `":selected => nil"` or to a value from a variable like `":selected => val"` in the select() in ruby but it is not working in either ways. Please can anyone tell what is wrong with the given below snippet.
Thanks

```
<%= select( map1[:field_name], "id", map1[:field_codes], :selected => nil )%>

<%= select( map1[:field_name], "id", map1[:field_codes], :selected => val )%>

where map1[:field_name] is a string 
and map1[:field_codes] returns a hash
val is a variable containing one of the values from hash.
```

Comment: Remember that the type of the `selected` option must match exactly, so if `val` is `2` and the entry in the `map1` data is `"2"`, then they're not the same. What is the contents of `map1[:field_codes]`?

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet works just fine. Tested it with

```
hash = { "n" => "no", "y" => "yes" }
val = "yes"
ActionView::Base::new.select("name", "id", hash, selected: val)
```

and it created:

```
<select id="name_id" name="name[id]">
   <option value="no">n</option>
   <option selected="selected" value="yes">y</option>
</select>
```

Either your `val` and `map1[:field_codes]` values aren't matching up *exactly* or if you start your Rails app and check the form to see `selected="selected"`, it could be an issue outside of Rails (like your browser).

Comment: <select id="ABC-XYZ10_id" name="ABC-XYZ10[id]"><option value="No">N</option>
<option value="Yes">Y</option></select>
So my out put looks like this, also i checked the val contains the exact value.
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try putting curly braces around the options:

```
 {:selected => val}
```

Comment: Does val contain an "id"?  Here's a format that works for me:        `<%= collection_select(:restaurant, :restaurant_id, Restaurant.all, :id, :name, {:selected => @party.restaurant_id} ) %>`

Comment: well I am new bee to ruby on rails, but my val does not contain any ID.
it goes like this
map1[:field_codes] = {"n"=>"no","y"=>"yes"}
and val will have = yes

Comment: The last argument to any method can be a free-form hash, there's no need for curly braces.